# Django view only returning primary key from field to template, no data

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views, django-oscar

I have a model which has a column categories in a Product table, which has one entry, 'beds'.

When I try to get a list of categories, or products (all of which have names, descriptions, etc), the only thing I can get returned is numbers.

This is the relevant view from my views.py

```
def product(request):
    template = loader.get_template('/home/user/webapps/webapp/my_site/main_page/templates/main_page/product.html')
    prods = xroduct.objects.values_list('product')
    context={'prods': prods}
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

This is my code within a django template to display data

```
{% for instance in prods %}
    <li>{{ instance }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

However, all that gets returned, going by HTML when viewing the webpage, is:

```
<li>(2,)</li>
<li>(1,)</li>
```

There should be a lot more information returned. Names, descriptions, etc. Why is this not being returned via my view?

edit: How xroduct is defined:

```
from oscar.core.loading import get_class, get_model

xroduct = get_model('catalogue', 'product')
```

Comment: Could you correct `xroduct` to what the actual name of the model you are using there?

Comment: what kind of field is `product` ?

Comment: @andreihondrari xroduct was not a typo. product is a textfield I think. I am editing my question to show the line defining xroduct.

Comment: Oh wait a minute, that's weird. You're basically talking about django-oscar, and that one has this model for "catalogue.product". 

https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/blob/master/src/oscar/apps/catalogue/abstract_models.py#L229

But that model shouldn't be having a "product" field on it...

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong but in that template, or on that page what you really want to do is list all the products?

Comment: Edit your question and be a bit more clear about this, also post the urls to reflect how you are accessing the view.

Comment: @andreihondrari I am indeed using django-oscar. I looked at the models.py but didn't really understand all the AbstractModel stuff, and it was differnt from other models.py formats I was familiar with.

I am indeed tryiing to get a list of products, but django-oscar seems to rely on using it's own get_model method which is different from what I understand. I have forked django-oscar apps to add another collection model, with every product belonging to a collection. I'm trying to get a list of product fields, names, image_urls, etc, and I am having a lot of trouble figuring out how to do so.

Comment: Yes, django-oscar has it's own special way of retrieving the model, which is that `get_model` you mentioned.

Comment: @andreihondrari I did have another question, this one ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53794448/django-view-only-returning-incomplete-data-only-one-field-to-template ), but wasn't sure the problem was specific to django-oscar so made a more narrow in scope question.

Comment: @andreihondrari ah, thankyou. My concern is that get_model will not be able to be used on a forked app that introduces its own models? I suppose that would be a question in and of itself.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185307/discussion-between-andreihondrari-and-jake-rankin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we are talking about `django-oscar` there are number of things to understand:

To retrieve the models from oscar you need to use `get_model` which is their own implementation of dynamically importing the models of interest.
`get_model` fetched the models from https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/blob/master/src/oscar/apps/catalogue/models.py whic are defined by https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/blob/master/src/oscar/apps/catalogue/abstract_models.py

What you need to do if you want to list products and their information is the following:

```
from oscar.core.loading import get_model

Product = get_model("catalogue", "Product")

def list_products(request):
    template = loader.get_template(...)
    products = Product.objects.all()
    context = {"products": products}
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

And in the template you can simply access the instances like:

```
{% for instance in prods %}
    <li>{{ instance.title }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I am unsure how to tell exactly what type of field product is at I am working with an app and the models.py is complex and not clear, but I assume it is some type of text field.